# Sequence of operators in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

In the space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ define a sequence of operators $(A_n)$ that are such that $||A_nf||=||f||$ and $\langle A_nf,g\rangle\to0$ for every $f,g\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$.

I have thought of defining $(A_n)f(x)=f(x+n)$ but I don't know how to proceed, can someone give me a hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct version of the question? Because it looks to me that every $A_n$ has to be the zero operator...

Comment: @paulgarrett but then $f$ has to be $0$.. Something funny is afoot.

Comment: Sorry there was a misprint in the question.

Comment: This still can't be right. If you take $g = A_n f$, then $\langle A_n f, A_n f\rangle = 0$ which implies that $A_n f = 0$. However since $0 = \|A_n f\| = \|f\|$, you can conclude that $f = 0$.

Comment: Something continues to be amiss: in your condition $\langle A_nf,g\rangle=0$, take $g=A_nf$, and then $A_nf=0$, for all $f$?

Comment: I am really sorry I had the wrong text of the exercise, the correct assumption is that $\langle A_nf,g\rangle\to0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thaught of taking
$$
A_n f=
\begin{cases}
f(x-n),\quad \text{if $x\ge n$}\\
0,\qquad \qquad\text{if $-n<x<n$}\\
f(x+n), \quad \text{if $x\le -n$}
\end{cases}
$$
It is an isometry, so $||A_n f||=||f||$.

$\langle A_n f,g\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{-n} f(x+n)\overline{g(x)}dx + \int_{n}^{+\infty} f(x-n) \overline{g(x)}dx$.

The two integrals are tails of convergent integrals (since $\langle A_n f,g\rangle<\infty$), so they tend to zero as $n\to +\infty$

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this question has had many iterations, but I'll react to what I see now in the hopes that I am right. My answer would be to essentially look at $A_n$, where it is  the $n$-shift operator on $\ell^2_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{N})$.

Take a countable orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and denote it by $\{ \phi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R}) $. For every $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ there is a unique sequence $\{ a_n(f) \}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that

$$ f=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k(f)\cdot \phi_k.$$

$A_n(f)$ will simply be

$$ A_n(f)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k}(f)\cdot \phi_{n+k}. $$

Notice that

$$ \langle A_n(f),\phi_{k} \rangle= \begin{cases} a_{k-n}(f) & ,k> n\\ 0 & ,k\leq n \end{cases}  $$

Hence, $\langle  A_n(f), \phi_k\rangle=0$ for $n$ large enough.

By Paresval's identity, we know that

$$\Vert A_n(f) \Vert^2= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \vert a_k(f)\vert^2. $$
Any finite linear combination

$$ g' = \sum_{j=1}^N c_j \cdot \phi_{k_j}, $$
satisfies that

$$  \langle A_n(f) ,\sum_{j=1}^N c_j \cdot \phi_{k_j}\rangle=0  $$

for $n$ large enough. Since the closure of the linear span of $\{ \phi_n \}$ is equal to $L^2$, you can deduce that

$$ \langle A_nf,g\rangle\to0 $$

for all $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Notice that $f$ was arbitrarily chosen here.